# URI getRawQuery vs getQuery

Tags: java, uri

I think that using [getQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#getQuery()) loses information, is dangerous and that instead only [getRawQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#getRawQuery()) should be used, and that any query parameter values that are known to be encoded should be manually decoded (once the raw query is split on the `&` characters) with [URLDecoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html).

Case in point: Assume you have the URL `www.example.com` with two query parameters:

- a parameter `url` with value `=www.otherexample.com?b=2&c=3`
- a nondescript parameter `d` with value 4.

The parameter `url` should be url-encoded, so the URI that your application sees is:

`www.example.com?url=www%2Eotherexample%2Ecom%3Fb%3D2%26c%3D3&d=4`

Now, if you obtain the query part with [getQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#getQuery()), you get the following:

`url=www.otherexample.com?b=2&c=3&d=4`

Notice that you've already lost information as you can't say whether `d` is a query parameter of the `www.example.com` or of `www.otherexample.com`.

If instead you obtain the query part with [getRawQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#getRawQuery()), you get the following:

`url=www%2Eotherexample%2Ecom%3Fb%3D2%26c%3D3&d=4`

This time, no information is lost and all's well. You can parse the query part and URL-decode the value of the `url` parameter if you like.

Am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're correct. 
URI.getQuery() is broken and you shouldn't use it.

Strange thing is I can't find any confirmation of this apart from your post, which made me think maybe URI.getQuery could be useful for something. But after some testing of my own I'm pretty sure it just shouldn't be used unless your application's query string doesn't follow the convention of separating arguments with ampersand.

EDIT 11/11/2019

As pointed out in a comment below, while you can use URI.getRawQuery() to work around the broken URI.getQuery() method, you can't just use the raw query as the query argument to the multi-argument URI constructor, as that constructor is also broken.

You can't use the multi-argument URI constructor if any of the query string arguments contain an ampersand. You could argue this is a bug, but the documentation of the expected behaviour contradicts itself so it's not clear which behaviour is correct. The javadoc of the multi-argument constructor says "Any character that is not a legal URI character is quoted". This implies that an escaped octet should NOT be quoted because the main class documentation includes it as a legal character ("The set of all legal URI characters consists of the unreserved, reserved, escaped, and other characters"). But further down, it documents the observed behaviour that the percent character ('%') is always quoted by the multi-argument constructors, which one assumes is without regard for whether it's part of an escaped octet.

Regardless of whether there is ever any acknowledgement that the documentation is contradictory, or what the correct behaviour should be, it is almost certain the current behaviour will never be altered. The only work-around is not to use the multi-argument constructors if you need the URI to end up containing the quoted ampersand octet "%26". Use the single-argument constructor instead, after doing your own encoding and quoting of special characters.

Comment: For anyone interested in what Oracle has to say, I've opened a bug report for this issue: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8214423

Comment: It is even worse. Using getRawQuery() does not help either. 
       `=======
        URI u = new URI("http://localhost/?x=Q%26A&y=2");
        URI u2 = new URI(u.getScheme(), u.getUserInfo(), u.getHost(), u.getPort(), u.getPath(),
                u.getRawQuery(), u.getFragment());
        System.out.println(u2);`
        
        prints: `http://localhost/?x=Q%2526A&y=2` **Double** encoded

Comment: Updated my answer to note this limitation of the URI constructor. Thanks @GeorgeDimitrov